# Trying to move data containing a certain string to a new dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to search through a read a .csv file into a dataframe, search through it for data that contains the string 'DSCRPT' and move it to another data frame and then merge them so i'll have two columns.
I have this so far:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('ctgs_list_ETS3.2.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') 

data.rename(columns={0:'ID'}, inplace=True)
word = 'DSCRPT'

data1 = df.loc[data['ID'].str.contains(word, case=False)]
data1
```

but at this point it crashes and I get the following errors:

KeyError: 'ID'
Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

Any help would be great.

Edit:

df = pd.read_csv('ctgs_list_ETS3.2.csv', encoding='utf-8')

```
df1 = df.iloc[:3000, :]
df2 = df.iloc[3000:, :]
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
df3
```

But I'm getting a data frame that looks like this:

__________________Id_x___Id_y
27 ^ID_CTG(28)='INC2MAY1' NaN

28 ^ID_CTG(29)='INC2MAY2' NaN

29 ^ID_CTG(30)='INC2PB_1' NaN

...
... ...

5970 NaN ^DSCRPT_CTG(2971)=' '

5971 NaN ^DSCRPT_CTG(2972)=' '

5972 NaN ^DSCRPT_CTG(2973)=' '

How do I get rid of the NaN values?

Comment: I think the 'r' parameter is wrong, you don't need it

Comment: `data.rename(columns={0:'ID'}, inplace=True)` do you data have a column name is 0 not string '0'?You cound check you `data.head()` after `rename()`

Comment: You dont need to import csv and probably also 'r' and encoding='utf-8'. In which line do you have the error?

Comment: @ Shihe Zhang for some reason 'ID' came out as 'Id' in the header, but now when I run the code I get an empty dataframe in data1 with two headers A and B...I'm not sure whats going on.

Comment: @Guiseppe The error's are gone now, data 1 is just not populating